# FactoryBot uninitialized constant FactoryName

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have the factory

```
FactoryBot.define do
    factory :activity_fit_file do
        association :user, factory: :user
        activity_type {:cycling}
        after(:build) do |activity|
            activity.original_activity_log_file.attach(
                io: File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/files/example_fit_file.fit"),
                filename: 'example_fit_file.fit',
                content_type: 'application/vnd.ant.fit'
            )
        end
    end
end
```

and in my spec I have

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Activity upload fixer" do
    it 'converts fit files to gpx' do
        activity = FactoryBot.create(:activity_fit_file)
    end
end
```

Running the spec gives the error

```
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant ActivityFitFile
```

Not quite sure what is wrong because it seems the same as other working factories.

Comment: Do you have a model called `ActivityFitFile`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No. I don't think there should be. The model is Activity and this is just an activity factory with different data. Typing that out though made me realize there is no way for factorybot to know what the actual model is called so I must have done something wrong there

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can have custom factory names, but you have to specify the actual classes then.

```
factory :activity_fit_file, class: 'Activity' do
  ···
end
```